# React Router useFetcher submit form with alt-enter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router and its useFetcher() hook.
I'm trying to submit fetcher.Form form with pressing alt-enter but it's not working.

I've created a sandbox displaying the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-tu-284rqh?file=/src/App.js

How can I get the same behaviour with alt-enter as with clicking the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestSubmit()` should be used instead of `submit()`

```
(ev.altKey && ev.key === "Enter") && ev.target.form.requestSubmit()
```